Join by multiple columns but only if values exists in one of the tables
I have two tables:
    drop table if exists #tbl1 
    create table #tbl1
    (
        col1 int  null
        ,col2 int  null
        ,col3 int  null
        ,col4 int not null
        ,col5 int not null
    )

with values
    insert into #tbl1 
    values(null, null, null, 1, 1039)
         ,(null, null, null, 1, 1214)
         ,(6541, null, null, 1, 1218)
         ,(null, 1425, null, 1, 1218)    

And I have the second table
    drop table if exists #tbl2
    create table #tbl2
    (
        col1 int  not null
        ,col2 int not null
        ,col3 int not null
        ,col4 int not null 
    )


tbl1.col1 is referenced by tbl2.col1
tbl1.col2 is referenced by tbl2.col2
tbl1.col3 is referenced by tbl2.col3
tbl1.col4 is referenced to tbl2.Col4.

My problem is to write a query which returns col5 by joining these two tables but only by the columns if the value of corresponding column in tbl2 exists in tbl1. For example: col5 = 1218 if tbl2 has the next row:
    insert into #tbl2
    values(6541, 12, 15, 1)

or col5 in (1039,1214) if tbl2 has the next row (tbl2.col1 and tbl2.col2 doesn't exists in tbl1.col1 and tbl1.col2 accordingly):
    insert into #tbl2 
    values(6542, 1413, 28, 1)

The only thing I came up with is dynamic SQL but I don't like an idea of 3 conditions with exists to tbl1
The second idea I came up with is a query like this:
select *
from tbl2 t2
left join tbl1 t1 on t1.col4= t2.col4
where (
          (
              exists
    (
        select 1
        from tbl1 t
        where t2.col1= t.col1
    )
          and t1.col1= t2.col1
          )
       or
           (
               not exists
    (
        select 1
        from tbl1 t
        where t2.col1= t.col1
    )
           and t1.col1 is null
           )
      )
  and
      (
          (
              exists
    (
        select 1
        from tbl1 t
        where t2.col2= t.col2
    )
          and t2.col2= t1.col2
          )
       or
           (
               not exists
    (
        select 1
        from tbl1 t
        where t2.col2= t.col2
    )
           and t1.col2 is null
           )
      )
  and
      (
          (
              exists
    (
        select 1
        from tbl1 t
        where t2.col3= t.col3
    )
          and t2.col3= t1.col3
          )
       or
           (
               not exists
    (
        select 1
        from tbl1 t
        where t2.col3= t.col3
    )
           and t1.col3 is null
           )
      );

But I think there is too much almost same selects to check if record exists to tbl1

Is this for SQL Server? If so, I suggest that you add a sql-server tag for greater visibility.

Please provide a complete [mre] i.e. show us the your desired results.

Is this some kind of filter "mask" join you're trying here? You really need to post very proper data from both tables and what you expect to get if you'll be able to explain this mess

Your description seemed confusing at first, but after reviewing your proposed solution, I believe I understand your requirements. To restate my understanding, a column is considered a match if:

The tbl1 and tbl2 values are equal, or
The tbl1 value is null and no other row in tbl1 has a matching value. (In other words, a null tbl1 value is a wildcard that matches any value except those explicitly present elsewhere in same the column.)

I can't think of any alternate ways of accomplishing this that significantly improve the query. I considered multiple separate left-joins to tbl1 (one for each column) that would somehow be reconciled with further conditions, COALESCE, and a final left-join - but that became even more complicated when I tried to develop it.
For your current query, I have a few suggestions:

If you really want to perform a left-join, you need to move all of the match conditions to the on condition. Leaving them in the where clause effectively changes the left-join to an inner-join.
The exists(... where t2.col<n> = t.col<n>) test is unnecessary since it is immediately followed by and t1.col<n> = t2.col<n> test.
Rearranging what's left (to put the simple conditions first) you have and (t1.col<n> = t2.col<n> or (t1.col<n> is null and not exists(select * from tbl1 t where t2.col<n> = t.col<n>)))

The trimmed query would them be something like:
select *
from tbl2 t2
left join tbl1 t1
    on t1.col4= t2.col4
    and (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or (
            t1.col1 is null
            and not exists(select * from tbl1 t where t2.col1 = t.col1)
        ))
    and (t1.col2 = t2.col2 or (
            t1.col2 is null
            and not exists(select * from tbl1 t where t2.col2 = t.col2)
        ))
    and (t1.col3 = t2.col3 or (
            t1.col3 is null
            and not exists(select * from tbl1 t where t2.col3 = t.col3)
        ))
;

For best performance, I recommend separate indexes on each col<n> column in tbl1.
Results (with an extra "no match* case):



col1
col2
col3
col4
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5




6541
12
15
1
6541
null
null
1
1218


6542
1413
28
1
null
null
null
1
1039


6542
1413
28
1
null
null
null
1
1214


6541
1425
28
1
null
null
null
null
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Here's an alternative solution perhaps: https://dbfiddle.uk/EJxR97ie which uses a ranking by non-null filters, i'm not sure the criteria for the filters exactly though
